# Nested object method calls from string

Tags: php

how call this in PHP:

```
$a = new Person();
$b = "method1()->method2()->method3()->methodn()";

$s->$b // doesn't work;
```

I don't want to explode by "->" and then call each method separately.

Comment: You would have to resort to [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), but every time I see this coming up, it's sign of bad design. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Extremely bad design, +1

Comment: Is the format fixed or do you simply want to store a chain of actions somehow in a variable? Might be a good idea to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

As long as they don't have any arguments, you **COULD** do this (Not that robust since it could be broken pretty easily by a malformed string.  But you could add a lot more error checking and support for arguments if you really tried)...:

```
$methods = explode('->', $b);

$ref = &$a;
foreach ($methods as $method) {
    $method = preg_replace('#\\(.*?\\)#', '', $method);
    $ref = &$ref->$method();
}
```

But I agree with NullUserException that it's typically a sign of bad design...  (I think chaining in general is a sign of bad design, but that's just my personal opinion)...

But either way, it's a lot safer than `eval`, so if you must, you may want to try something like this...

**Edit:**  Based on your updated answer (wanting to map a function to an array of objects):

Using php 5.3:

```
$newArray = array_map(
    function($value) { 
        return $value->parent()->name;
    },
    $array
);
```

Or with PHP <= 5.2:

```
$func = create_function('$value', 'return $value->parent()->name;');
$newArray = array_map($func, $array);
```

So, your final `map` method becomes:

```
public function map($string) {
    $func = create_function('$value', 'return $value' . $string . ';');
    $return = array();
    foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
        $return[$key] = $func($value);
    }
}
```

Since it's not an array, `array_map` won't work directly...  But you can iterate over the object itself.

But beware, this is no safer than `eval`, so you really should look at a different solution (such as mapping a callback):

```
public function map($callback) {
    $return = array();
    foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
        $return[$key] = $callback($value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$array = $collection->map(function($value) { return $value->parent()->name; });
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding eval. Actually, very close to what I was going to suggest, only I have an addiction to recursive functions.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to check into "eval":

```
eval('$a' . $b);
```

But beware: Unless you control `$b` yourself, you might be opening yourself up for bad things to happen. This can be a major security hole if `$b` comes from any source the user can change or leak changes to!

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do sth like ruby map for my own collection object (build on arrayobject). If I have array of objects I wont to do sth like this:

```
$people->map('name') //which should return array of names
```

or

```
$people->map('parent()->name') //which should return array of names of parents
```

Comment: @ircmaxell: your last tip (with callback) is closest to my thoughts. Unfortunately i cant vote up (low reputation)